# Running karma-jasmin tests on selenium grid

Tags: selenium, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, selenium-grid

We've got our tests for angularjs code using Jasmin and currently running with Karma. The tests are now using phantomjs.
Is there a way to run these tests using selenium grid?
It seems there is 'https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-webdriver-launcher' which can do the trick; however, this is not an option for us. Is there another way to run our tests using the selenium grid?